# AJAX calls [object%20Object] instead of URL (Symfony)

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony, url, routes

In twig I use `data-post-url="{{ path('ajax')}}"` so I can get the url in javascript by using `var path = $("#edit-url-js").data();`

However instead of going to http://localhost/happysaucer/web/app_dev.php/ajax it goes to
http://localhost/happysaucer/web/app_dev.php/profile/[object%20Object]

Which is weird because when I console.log(path) the 'path' variable it return the right url. When I hardcode the url the 'path' variable returns the ajax call works like it should.

AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var path = $("#edit-url-js").data();

$(".option-js").on("change", function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: "post",
        data: "test",
        success: function(data) {

        }
    });

});
});
```

Controller Action

```
/**                                                                                   
* @Route("/ajax", name="ajax")
*/
public function ajaxAction(Request $request)    
{

    $r = new JsonResponse();

    return $r->setData([
        'success' => true,
    ]);
}
```

Twig code

```
<div class="consumeable-container" id="edit-url-js" data-post-url="{{ path('ajax')}}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really strange that you are getting the right URL when doing console.log(path), but it may change from where you're calling it, because of context, maybe there is a global path variable somewhere?

Anyway there are 3 ways to get that URL correctly:

jQuery:

```
var path = $("#edit-url-js").data("post-url")
var path = $("#edit-url-js").attr("data-post-url")
```

Pure Javascript:

```
var path = document.getElementById("#data-post-url").getAttribute("data-post-url")
```

But I suggest you to put the URL on your option event to make it exclusive to that option, only in case you want it exclusive, like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".option-js").on("change", function() {
      var $optionElement = $(this)
        $.ajax({
          url: $optionElement.data("post-url"),
          type: "post",
          data: "test",
          success: function(data) {
          }
        });
    });
});
```